# IIS10.0: Restrict user access to a specific website

Tags: iis-10, windows-server-2019

We have 2 websites A & B and users as AA & BB. User AA should **only** be able to import application, Start, Stop & Restart website A. Same goes with user BB for website B.
Also when user AA logs in then other website B should have this symbol:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIv7q.png

Have tried following things:

1. Added users to IIS Manager Permissions.
2. Added users to IIS Manager Users too.
3. Changed Identity to specific user at App pool level.

But it's not working as intended.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: The design of IIS only allows you to use feature delegation to set users as site administrators, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/an-overview-of-feature-delegation-in-iis#iis-manager--creating-site-and-application-administrators You get nothing more than that.

Comment: If users AA and BB are on the same server with IIS, it may be difficult to achieve. If they connect to server remotely, you can only allow users connect to a site. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtBkT.png